# Display a link to the status of my latest tweet using jQuery & how to execute it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have jQuery in the `<head>` of my page as this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="./javascript/jquery-1.2.6.js"></script>
```

and already I was gratefully given this code that will display a linked text that reads 'Read' and the link will be to my latest tweet's status and it looks like this:

```
jQuery.getJSON('http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/brianj_smith.json?count=1&callback=?', function(data){
if (data.length > 0) {
    var link = jQuery('<a>').attr('http://twitter.com/brianj_smith/status/' + data[0].id)
                            .text('Read');
});
```

Now I am not an expert at jQuery, so I don't exactly know how to make the above jQuery coding work and for the text "Read" to be displayed on my website, while at the same time it being linked to the status of my latest tweet.

I think that makes sense for the most part. If anyone could help me out that would be great. I know I made a post earlier, but I didn't understand much of what was being said :S

Comment: Any reason to use jQuery 1.2, when jQuery 1.5 is out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would just add @Ben's code in your existing:

```
jQuery.getJSON('http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/brianj_smith.json?count=1&callback=?', function(data){
$('#tweetlink').append('<a href="http://twitter.com/brianj_smith/status/' + data[0].id_str + '">Read Tweet</a>');
});
```

Comment: My problem is that it won't show up on my website... No text or link to the latest status shows up in the body of my website. Am I doing something incorrect?

Comment: See my edited answer above. Instead of creating a new element, I just appended html with the twitter link injected into it. Let me know if that works.
Also, be sure to put #div-name, not just div-name, you probably figured that out though. :-)

Comment: This is what I have in the body of my website: 


`<div id="tweetlink"></div> `


and this is the code I have above the `</body>` tag:


`<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.getJSON('http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/brianj_smith.json?count=1&callback=?', function(data){
$('#tweetlink').append('<a href="http://twitter.com/brianj_smith/status/' + data[0].id + '">Read Tweet</a>");
});
</script>`

-- but it still isn't showing the "Read Tweet". Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you have the page somewhere that I could investigate?

Comment: sure one sec, i will upload it for you!

Comment: See my edited post above. It was a stupid error on my part: I accidentally put a " instead of a ' :-)

Copy the code from above, and the link appears.

Comment: One more thing: the id property of data is slightly off. You need to use id_str, then it works.

Comment: Great, it shows now. but for some reason when you click the tweet, it says that the page doesn't exist? Any idea why this is?

Comment: you need to change `data[0].id` to `data[0].id_str`

Comment: Amazing. thanks for your help! I've chosen it as the answer :)

Comment: I'm trying to, but it keeps telling me to login. I'm logged in. I'll keep trying!

Comment: Don't worry about it. Glad I could help you.

Comment: I need 15 reputation points apparently to vote it up. I'll come back to this post when I hit that and vote it up! :) thanks for the help again!

Comment: Haha, that's funny. I guess I never tried to upvote something with less than 15 rep. 
You're very welcome, Brian!

Comment: And there you go! I managed to get it within that minute of posting the last reply. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You would use jQuery to get a reference to the element that should contain your link and append the newly created `link`:

```
$('div-to-contain-the-link').append(link);
```

Comment: How do I use that? would i add it to the existing code I posted?

Comment: Yes - in theory, anyway.  I'd have to see the broader context of your page to be sure, but the idea was that you could just insert this line in your `if` block after you initialize the `link` variable.